How do i export a file to open into my slice program
After i have smoothed out a file and save it stl when i reopen it in a slicer program it shows its still low poly looking. I have watched videos but i just can't figure it out.

How did you "smooth out" the file? Setting it to Shade Smooth is just a display method, it is not actually making the object smoother or high poly.
